# Office Ribbon: How to access a control when the ribbon was created using XML

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I used a ribbon XML file to create a custom tab which contains a togglebutton.  The button is meant to toggle the visibility of a custom task pane and works great.  The problem is that when the user close the custom task pane, the toggle button is now out of sync.  How do I programmaticly access the togglebutton so I can change its IsChecked value?

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle the [VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.visiblechanged.aspx) event. Add the following method to your ThisAddIn class - when the user closes the task pane by clicking the Close button (X), this method updates the state of the toggle button on the Ribbon.

```
private void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked = 
        taskPaneValue.Visible;
}
```

*(see more info on this in [Walkthrough: Synchronizing a Custom Task Pane with a Ribbon Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608590.aspx))*