# RibbonDropDown losing items

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon, office-2010

I'm adding items to a `RibbonDropDown` that is used by the **New Email inspector** at run time. I add the items on start-up and also refresh the list on demand (*when the user presses a button*)

```cs
public void RefreshListNames()
{
    Logger.Log("Refresh Mail Lists");

    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.rddListNames.Items.Clear();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> kvp in _dda.GetMarketingListNames())
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonDropDownItem dd = 
            Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();

        dd.Tag = kvp.Key;
        dd.Label = kvp.Value;

        Logger.Log("Adding " + dd.Label);

        Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.rddListNames.Items.Add(dd);

    }

    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.rddListNames.ResumeLayout();
}
```

**Note:** `rddListNames` is a `RibbonDropDown`

This method is called in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` method and populated corectly on start-up. However, any new Mail window ends up with a blank dropdown - no items. Even refreshing the list doesn't add the items back again.

I added some logging: it shows that the method is running when the 'refresh button' is pressed:

```
23/04/2013 14:36:43 - Refresh Mail Lists 
23/04/2013 14:36:45 - Adding Marketing List - Dynamic 
23/04/2013 14:36:45 - Adding Marketing List - Bs 
23/04/2013 14:36:45 - Adding Marketing List - As
```

Why does the drop down keep loosing items? And why don't they come back, even if I explicitly refresh them?

Comment: I also tried Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.rddListNames.ResumeLayout(); - though since I am not explicitly suspending layout, unsurprisingly, this didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you using the [**Ribbon XML** or **Ribbon Designer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9379747/175679)?

Comment: I was using the designer - but can export the designed ribbon to xml for hand editing if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make control modifications to the **Ribbon UI**, you need to invalidate the **control cache** via [`IRibbonControl.Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or [`IRibbonControl.InvalidateControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa433553%28v=office.12%29.aspx). This will trigger a repaint of the Ribbon elements.

```cs
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.Invalidate();
// or...
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.InvalidateControl("ddMarketingList");
```

Comment: I have tried this - added after the loop that clears/re-instates the dropdown items. However, it still doesn't work - still blank. Is there a specific way to call this? (I can't find an example of doing it any other way). Thanks

Comment: I have also tried Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.rddListNames.PerformDynamicLayout(); and dd.Parent.PerformDynamicLayout();