# How to migrate Outlook 2007 Addin that was developed with VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Some time ago I developed an Outlook 2007 Addin with VS2008. I now want to continue development but would like to use VS2010. As in VS2010 there is still a Template for Office 2007 I thought I could just load my 2008 Solution into VS2010 an compile, but it fails with a lot of Errors like:

```
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(14,33): error CS0115: 'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(3,19): error CS0535:   'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon.DefaultExtension'
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.cs(11,26): (Related location)
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(3,19): error CS0535: 'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon.Extension'
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.cs(11,26): (Related location)
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(3,19): error CS0535: 'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon.Context'
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.cs(11,26): (Related location)
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(3,19): error CS0535: 'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon.Global'
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.cs(11,26): (Related location)
C:\Entwicklung\EasyGigTracker\EasyGigTracker\RibbonMail.Designer.cs(3,19): error CS0535: 'EasyGigTracker.GigTrackerMailRibbon' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon.OfficeMenu'
```

Is there a way to get it work with VS2010?

Comment: I've not used **VSTO3**, but this may just be an issue of upgrading from **VSTO3** to **VSTO4**. You may have to start over with your Ribbon modifications. **Ribbon XML** is also the preferred way to go now as opposed to using the **Ribbon Designer** that you are currently using.

Comment: Yes, it looks like. I started a new project and added piece by piece. Why is XML the preferred way?

Comment: It's preferred as the designer is limited in capabilities - the drag and drop designer is typically the starting point for new developers to ease the learning curve, while advanced developers learn the Ribbon XML model which requires a bit more plumbing. In Outlook 2010+ [**ContextMenus** and **Backstage view** is only available via Ribbon XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx). It can also give you [improved rendering performance if you are frequently updating the Ribbon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9379747/175679).

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I have seen, its always possible to convert a designer ribbon to a XML-Ribbon, so I don't limit myself at the moment.